# How to clean invalid characters from Invoke-RestMethod for input to Invoke-Expression?

Tags: powershell, github

After moving a gist to a github repo, it seems the github repo returns an invalid character at the start of the string?

I'm not sure if this is caused by msys-git committing to the repo?

```
>irm "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/so0k/ParseCsvLetour/master/Parse.ps1" | iex 

#Script : The term '#Script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ #Script to parse csv file
+ ~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to clean invalid characters from Invoke-RestMethod before executing the downloaded script?

However, If I send the contents to a file using `-OutFile` and execute the script, it works, but I want to avoid it throwing errors when `ExecutionPolicy` does not allow the execution of the script.

EDIT: Or I could fix it by ensuring the script is cleaned up using github editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the github web editor and noticed a strange character in the script, after removing it, all works again.

I suspect msys git added the character when I committed the code to the repository...